# cmder alias: use several files as macrofile

Tags: alias, cmder, doskey

I use several configurations in my cmder. So I defined several tasks to be able to run them in specific tab.
Today, I have duplicate `cmder\config` to `cmder\config_1`, `cmder\config_2` etc. And in each config folder, I define specific aliases for this config in `\cmder\config_x\user_aliases.cmd`.

The problem is a have to duplicate my common aliases in each `\cmder\config_x\user_aliases.cmd` and if I want to add a new one, I have to edit all the `user_aliases.cmd` files to add it in all my config.

Is there a way to load several aliases files in a task, e.g. `cmder\config\user_aliases.cmd` and `\cmder\config_x\user_aliases.cmd`  ?

Ideally, I would like to use several files to define my aliases:

- a `\cmder\config\user_aliases.cmd` with my common aliases
- several `\cmder\config_x\user_aliases.cmd` files with specific aliases

And load aliases from both files in my dedicated task